# Java-BackGround color never applying

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change the background color of buttons programatically in my Android application, but it does not work.
Whatever methods I am using work fine, (i.e text size, text, text color) but I cannot manage to change the background color of the buttons.
What am I doing wrong ?

XML description of the button :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/jeton103"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="28"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#2aa17b" />
```

Java code :

```
int i;
            int j = 103;
            Button changer;
            private EditText changerlettres;
            String choix;



public void BtnClick() {

          changer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Thrown out letters

            choix = changerlettres.getText().toString(); // EditText

            for (int i = 0, n = choix.length(); i < n; i++) {
                char letter = choix.charAt(i);
                final Button jetoninvisible;

                int ressourceId2 = getResources().getIdentifier("jeton"+j, "id", getPackageName());
                jetoninvisible = (Button) findViewById(ressourceId2);

                // jetoninvisible.getBackground().setAlpha(200); // Not working
                // jetoninvisible.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); Not working
     // jetoninvisible.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#eeceac")); // Not working
                jetoninvisible.setTextSize(40); // Working fine
                jetoninvisible.setText(String.valueOf(letter)); // Working fine

                j = j+1;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks a lot for your answers or suggestions

Comment: How many buttons are there?

Comment: About one hundred

Comment: Try removing `android:backgroundTint="#2aa17b"` and set `android:background="#2aa17b"`

Comment: That's it ! Thank you mTak, my stuff is working now.

Comment: I'm glad_______